# Noisy CPU Fan in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, fan, dell-inspiron, cpu-speed

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop with Windows 8.1. The CPU fan is quiet when I use Windows. I installed Linux Mint with Cinnamon on another partition, but the fan is noisy all the time when I use Linux Mint. Is there a way to slow down the fan while using Mint without disturbing how it works on Windows?

Comment: [This is a question about fan control on Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/393988/ubuntu-toshiba-fan-speed-issue?rq=1) the solution on Mint will be very similar.

Comment: "Slow down the fan"? Most likely it's running hard because of lack of power saving features on the GPU. Not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

On my Dell Inspiron 5548 I have had to add "acpi_osi=Linux" to the Grub configuration so SpeedStep could kick in and the CPU frequency adjusted. This way the fans are not at maximum speed anymore.